# Adding One to a number stored as an Array

Tags: code-challenge

I was challenged by one of my friends to solve this coding problem:

Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits, add one to the number. The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list. Return the value as a new list.

This was my solution, which does not work if [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] is input.

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    int[] ret;
    int integervalue;
    integervalue = 0;
    String stringvalue;
    for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
        integervalue = integervalue*10 + digits[i];
    }
    integervalue++;
    stringvalue = String.valueOf(integervalue);
    ret = new int[stringvalue.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < stringvalue.length(); i++) {
        ret[i] = stringvalue.charAt(i) - 48;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My apologies if my code is confusing, awkward, hard-to-read, or if the solution is incredibly obvious. I am still a rookie in Java.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This site is for programming competitions, not for general programming questions. For those you can try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but make sure to check out their Help Center first to ensure your question is on topic. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf&ProgrammingPuzzles.SE! Don't be discouraged by the closing of your challenge! typically, we encourage users to post in the sandbox for a few days for critiquing. You can find thet here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1

Comment: @tuskiomi firstly there aren't any downvotes. Second, this question could never be on-topic for this site

Comment: @muddyfish sure. I fixed it..

Comment: FYI `int` will overflow for that input.

Comment: I think this could be a reasonable code golf, though "stored as an array" could be tricky to define in a language-independent way.